# Multiple Setup files for ClickOnce application (for different versions) - Concurrently

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce

I want to be able to install either version of the **same** program (The exact same one. As in: one installation will overwrite the other.) . But I can't have them in different folders because a ClickOnce application can only be installed from one folder.

I can have multiple setup files because I've found that I can rename setup.exe. Also, I can have all of the actual versions of the program because all versions coexist in "Application files" folder.

However, the "Deployment Manifest" files (i.e. the **.application** files) are a problem - A new one will overwrite an old one, and renaming would simply cause the renamed one to be ignored.

So how can I have one setup file - setup1.exe - install version 1.0.0.1, and setup2.exe install version 1.0.0.2?

Comment: That's not how ClickOnce was designed. It will upgrade/replace earlier versions.

Comment: @jrummell That's fine. If I decide to install version 1 over version 2 - that's exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do ...

Comment: @jrummell I want to have two setup files. If I click on one - I install version 1. If I click on the other - I install version 2.